# grep to find an exact word match with a period in it

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, grep

I have a huge `.csv` file in this format:

```
"acc","lineage"
"MT993865","B.1.509"
"MW483477","B.1.402"
"MW517757","B.1.2"
"MW517758","B.1.2"
"MW592770","B.1.564"
...
```

i.e, the first column is a string representing the `accession_id` of the data sample and the second column is a covid variant `lineage`. I would like to extract accession_ids along with their lineage for a few specific variants of interest, for example, `Omicron` i.e. `B.1.1.529`. I tried to grep the file with `-w` but since `.` is a non-word character, it fetches me the results of variants that extend omicron for example, `B.1.1.529.1`

For **elaborated** discussion, please have a look at this bash script I wrote:

```
# filter data based on the selected lineages (refer to variants_lineage.txt for more info) as given below.

# File with metadata
metadata_file="$HOME/thesis/SARS-CoV2-data/metadata.csv"
cat "$metadata_file" | tr -d '"' | tr ',' $'\t' > adj_metadata.tsv

# list of lineages of interest
selected_lineages=("B.1.1.7" "B.1.351" "P.1" "B.1.617.2" "B.1.1.5290" "C.37" "B.1.621" "B.1.429" "B.1.427" "CAL.20C" "P.2" "B.1.525" "P.3" "B.1.526" "B.1.617.1" )
pattern=$(echo ${selected_lineages[*]}|tr ' ' '|')

if [ -f "adj_metadata.tsv" ]
then
  echo "File exists"
  for lineage in ${selected_lineages[@]}
    do
      echo "Filtering for lineage $lineage"
      grep -w "$lineage" adj_metadata.tsv >> filtered_metadata.tsv
    done
else
  echo "Adjusted metadata file does not exist."
fi

# Check for the uniqueness of the filtered_metadata.csv file, this should fetch the list of selected_lineages
cut -d$'\t' -f2 filtered_metadata.tsv | sort | uniq
```

Any suggestions/advice are very much appreciated.

And also please feel free to comment on improvements that are not related to the question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that it makes it easier for others to help you if your example data is consistent with your script and your explanation. That way others don't need to craft data according to your explanation to test your problem.

Comment: @mashuptwice sorry for not providing the complete info, the metadata.csv file is pretty huge, it's hard to provide all the unique variant values.

Comment: @RajeshM the `.csv` example you provided doesn't contain either or the strings (`B.1.1.529` or `B.1.1.529.1`) you later said you were having problems with. These sort of omissions make it more difficult to provide help.

Comment: My point is not to provide all unique variants. You've used `B.1.1.529` in your explanation, which is nowhere to be found in the script and the csv. At the same time not a single value in your script is found in the csv.

Comment: point noted! Thank you both for your clarifications.

Comment: OK, but please [edit] your question and add example data we can actually use to help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Method 1

Since the string in your .csv is always between double-quotes `"`, you could include the quotes in your match. You then simply use single quotes `'` for the expression.

**Example:**

`asdf.csv:`

```
"foo","B.1.1.529"
"bar","B.1.1.529.1"
```

```
╰─$ grep  '"B.1.1.529"' ./asdf
"foo","B.1.1.529"
```

As you see `B.1.1.529.1` will not match in this case.

---

##### Method 2

While method 1 would work with your input data, it would not with the `adj_metadata.tsv` as it is stripped of all quotes. You could of course modify your script to first match and then pipe the output through `tr`, but that would include unnecessary work.

What you could do there is anchor the regular expression to the end of the line with `$`

**Example:**

`adj-metadata.tsv:`

```
foo     B.1.1.529
bar     B.1.1.529.1
```

```
╰─$ grep "B.1.1.529$" adj_metadata.tsv
foo     B.1.1.529
```

The only modification you'll need to make to your script with this method is to add `\$` at the right spot in your grep command:

```
#!/bin/bash
# filter data based on the selected lineages (refer to variants_lineage.txt for more info) as given below.

# File with metadata
metadata_file="$HOME/thesis/SARS-CoV2-data/metadata.csv"
cat "$metadata_file" | tr -d '"' | tr ',' $'\t' > adj_metadata.tsv

# list of lineages of interest
selected_lineages=("B.1.1.7" "B.1.351" "P.1" "B.1.617.2" "B.1.1.5290" "C.37" "B.1.621" "B.1.429" "B.1.427" "CAL.20C" "P.2" "B.1.525" "P.3" "B.1.526" "B.1.617.1" )

#replace all occurrences of "." with "\."
selected_lineages=$(echo $selected_lineages | sed 's/\./\\./g')

if [ -f "adj_metadata.tsv" ]
then
  echo "File exists"
  for lineage in ${selected_lineages[@]}
    do
      echo "Filtering for lineage $lineage"
      grep -w "$lineage\$" adj_metadata.tsv >> filtered_metadata.tsv
    done
else
  echo "Adjusted metadata file does not exist."
fi

# Check for the uniqueness of the filtered_metadata.csv file, this should fetch the list of selected_lineages
cut -d$'\t' -f2 filtered_metadata.tsv | sort | uniq
```

---

Note: While `.` is usually used as an expression for any character, you would need to escape with a `\` to search for a literal `.` like so: `B\.1\.1\.529$`.

You could still keep it without `\`, for the sake of simplicity while typing.

Comment: tysm, it almost did. however `B.1.1.7` matches records with `B.117` and so on. As you said, the `period` is being considered as any character.

Comment: @RajeshM I've modified the script further to account for that edgecase.

Comment: `sed` does not replace all characters of `.` with `\.` though g is provided. So it now matches B.1.17.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with the data you've provided in the script. This is the content of pattern: `B\.1\.509|B\.1\.1\.529|B\.1\.351|P\.1|B\.1\.617\.2|B\.1\.1\.5290|C\.37|B\.1\.621|B\.1\.429|B\.1\.427|CAL\.20C|P\.2|B\.1\.525|P\.3|B\.1\.526|B\.1\.617\.1` As you can see, every single instance of `.` got replaced with `\.`

Comment: It worked! :D

Mistakenly you have added `sed` to the `pattern` variable which I have not used. Adding a line "lineage=$(echo $lineage | sed `s:\.:\\.:g`" worked. Thank you once again for the time and help.

Comment: @RajeshM I've further improved your edit so that `sed` only needs to run once.